# Why is there no cuda afer I installed pytorch with cuda?

Tags: windows, pytorch, conda

I typed

```
conda install pytorch torchvision torchaudio pytorch-cuda=11.8 -c pytorch -c nvidia on windows but get no cuda available
```

and successfully installed pytorch with cuda on my environment on windows.
I checked the

```
conda list
```

and found pytorch-cuda 11.8 and pytorch2.0.1.

However, when I

```
print(torch.version.cuda)
```

I got 'None'.

When I

```
print(torch.cuda.is_available())
```

I got 'False'.

Is it possible that the cuda 11.8 is messed up with cuda 11.3 (works well) on another environment?
I tried a couple of hours still can't solve it.
[nvidia driver](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AdN0t.png)
I think the GPU is fine.
It will really help if you give me some hints.
Thank you!

Comment: The "on windows but get no cuda available" inside the first code block seems misplaced. It also doesn't sound like you "successfully installed pytorch with cuda".

Comment: You are installing `pytorch` and `torchvision` vanilla versions, without CUDA.  Then you also install a version with CUDA support.  With multiple installed versions, it's anyone's guess what `import torch` in your frontend is going to find.  Don't install the vanilla versions.